# What does this command do in VSCode's CLI launch script?

Tags: bash, syntax, variable-assignment

In VSCode's (MacOS) [launch script](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/94c9ea46838a9a619aeafb7e8afd1170c967bb55/resources/darwin/bin/code.sh), we can find the following lines:

```
CONTENTS="$(dirname "$(dirname "$(dirname "$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")")")")"
ELECTRON="$CONTENTS/MacOS/Electron"
CLI="$CONTENTS/Resources/app/out/cli.js"
ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 "$ELECTRON" "$CLI" "$@"
```

What is going on with the last line (which actually goes and executes the CLI)? Why is there a 1 in front of the command?

Comment: That's the value of the environment variable `ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put a variable assignment at the beginning of a shell command, it sets that environment variable temporarily while running the command. So the last line is effectively equivalent to:

```
(
    export ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1
    "$ELECTRON" "$CLI" "$@"
)
```

The parentheses put the commands in a subshell, so the variable assignment doesn't persist.

Comment: Oh my, the fact that the command came from a string confused me for some reason. Oops, thanks.